# MYSQL query SELECT from one table and join results with other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `MESSAGES` and `USERS`:

`MESSAGES`:

```
|id|user_id|message|1st number|2nd number|
```

`USERS`:

```
|user_id|name|
```

I'm trying to display a message and by user_id get username next to the message. Is it possible to do it in just one query?

At this moment my demo query looks like that but it does not work.

```
SELECT *
 FROM   messages
 WHERE  1st number BETWEEN $x AND $z
 AND 2nd BETWEEN $x AND $z
 LEFT JOIN users
 ON users.user_id= messages.user_id
 ORDER BY time DESC
```

The error which I get: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN users ON WHERE users.user_id= messages.user_id ORDER BY time DESC' at line 5

Comment: You already said it in your question; you can JOIN them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: What error message do you get?  Also, does the following work?
"SELECT * FROM messages LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=messages.user_id"

If not, what is the error message you get for the latter query?

Comment: '1st number' is this your real field name ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your SQL:

- if a column name contains spaces, you need to quote them
- you need to write the full column names in mysql
- JOIN comes before WHERE

So something like

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
 LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id=messages.user_id
WHERE `1st number` BETWEEN $x AND $z
 AND `2nd number` BETWEEN $x AND $z
ORDER BY time DESC
```

should work

Comment: Thanks, this one worked out. Just one newbie question. So when trying to get results from multiple tables, first of all you need to JOIN all of them and then filter?

Comment: SQL select works by defining a "query view" - one or more tables, subqueries or database views joined together, then filtering, grouping, group-filtering it. So you have `SELECT`... field list ... `FROM` ... view definition with joins and subqueries ... `WHERE` ... row filters ... `GROUP BY` ... grouping parameters ... `HAVING` ... group filters ... `ORDER BY` ordering parameters. Ofcourse some of this is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = messages.user_id
WHERE
        `1st number` BETWEEN $x AND $z
    AND
        `2nd number` BETWEEN $x AND $z
ORDER BY time DESC
```